# AsyncTask is not working second time even if I create new instance (Android)

Tags: android, android-service

I'm new to Android. I'm learning services.

I have created a foreground service MyIntentService.java. It has a counter variable that increments every second and displays its value in the notification. I don't have any problem with the service.

I want to get this counter value in the MainActivity.java and displays its value in a TextView. As the counter variable updates (increments) every second in the Service class, the TextView in the MainActivity should be updated every second.

The thing I know is I cannot update TextView in main thread. I have to create a new thread. So, I added AsyncTask.

When I first launch the app, the service is running, and the TextView is getting updated continuously. Everything is fine. But, when I close the app (the service is still running), and opens it, AsyncTask is not working at all. The TextView is not getting updated.

Here is the MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public boolean isServiceConnected;

    long count;
    private TextView tvShowSeconds;
    private SwitchCompat switch11;

    private Intent serviceIntent;
    private ServiceConnection serviceConnection;
    private MyIntentService myIntentService;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //TextView (tvShowSeconds) displays the counter value (from the Service)
        tvShowSeconds = findViewById(R.id.tvShowSeconds);
        
        //I added switch to test if the UI is responding or not
        switch11 = findViewById(R.id.switch11);
        
        serviceIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyIntentService.class);
        bindService();
        ContextCompat.startForegroundService(getApplicationContext(), serviceIntent);

        new MyAsyncClass().execute("Something");
    }

    public void bindService() {
        if (serviceConnection == null) {
            serviceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
                @Override
                public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
                    MyIntentService.MyServiceBinder myServiceBinder = (MyIntentService.MyServiceBinder) service;
                    myIntentService = myServiceBinder.getService();
                    isServiceConnected = true;
                }

                @Override
                public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
                    isServiceConnected = false;
                }
            };
        }
        bindService(serviceIntent, serviceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }

    public class MyAsyncClass extends AsyncTask<String, Long, Long> {
        @Override
        protected Long doInBackground(String... strings) {
            try {
                //Service is not binding immediately. So, I added 5 seconds delay.
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            long count = 0;
            while (isServiceConnected) {
                //Get the counter value from the service.
                count = myIntentService.getSeconds();
                publishProgress(count);
            }
            return count;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Long... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
            //Update the TextView with the counter value.
            tvShowSeconds.setText(String.valueOf(values[0]));
        }
    }
}
```

My requirement is:

Whenever I launch the app, the TextView should be updated continuously with the counter value. The service should run forever and AsyncTask should not run when the app is closed. It should start and end with MainActivity. Can anyone please tell me how to do this?

Also, please tell me, is AsyncTask correct in this situation. Is there any thread type class (or API) that starts with the MainActivity and stops when the MainActivity is destroyed?

The app contains just two classes MainActivity.java and MyIntentService.java.
Here is the manifest file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.servicesexp">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.ServicesExp">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service android:name=".MyIntentService">
        </service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: `The thing I know is I cannot update TextView in main thread.` Not true. You cannot update TextView from another thread.

Comment: AsyncTask is definitely not the right thing for a continuously running thread.  Use a Thread.  Also, all AsyncTasks run on the same thread, so if you have one looping like this no other async tasks will ever run.

Comment: Then please tell me how to solve this problem

Comment: Hi Kumar. This line, "new MyAsyncClass().execute("Something");" returns an ASyncTask and you can call "cancel()" on it from the appropriate lifecycle method such as onStop(). But since you are new to Android and learning I just want to point out that ASyncTask and IntentService are both deprecated and should not be used for new apps. Kind Regards.